# Split Date in format(YYYY-MM-DD) into 3 new columns in dataframe as Year , Month & Date

Tags: python, pandas, date

How can i split a string in example below into new columns as Year Month and Date in dataframe.

Example: Column A in a data frame

```
Column A
2017-10-15
```

Expected output result in dataframe

```
Column A    Year  Month Date 
2017-10-15   2017   10    15
```

Answer (score 6):

```
df['year']= df['Date'].dt.year
df['month']= df['Date'].dt.month
df['day']= df['Date'].dt.day
```

This will work only if 'Column A' is in datetime format. you can do that with 
`df['Column A']= pd.to_datetime(df['Column A'],format='%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: Thank you! this is want i needed.